# Как получить id письма на почте? Python

Tags: python, imap

```
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login("почта", "пароль")

    # выбираем папку All Mail

    folder = [re.sub(r'.*?("\[G[^"]*").*', r'\1', f.decode("utf-8")) for f in mail.list()[1] if 
    br"\All " in f][0]
    mail.select(folder)

    typ, data = mail.search(None, 'FROM', "почта_отправителя")
    mb.showinfo("Окно",  random.choice(data))

    # Выбор случайного id письма
```

И вот на этом моменте мне выдает список id писем от почты отправителя[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше мне нужно из этого списка выбрать случайное число, я использовал -  random.choice(data),
но он не выдает мне почему-то случайное число из списка, а просто дублирует его без скобочек.
Как я еще могу получить случайное число из этого списка?

Либо же, как я могу получить сразу id письма от конкретного отправителя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
data = list(data) 
random.choice(data)
```